# How to run "mongodb --repair" if it's an Upstart job?

Tags: mongodb, upstart

My MongoDB server died. The log says something about an unclean shutdown and an existing `mongodb.lock` file. It recommends to remove the lock file, then restart the mongodb server with `--repair`.

However, on my system (Ubuntu 10.10), I've installed MongoDB via an `apt-get` package, and it's set up as Upstart job. If I run `mongodb` from the command line, it won't find the data, none of the paths are set correctly. Surely, I could read the man page, try to emulate what Upstart would do, give it all the correct parameters plus `--repair` but that seems like a lot of trouble. There must be a simpler way, that's not fighting Upstart. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Quick Workaround:* Start mongodb and then immediately afterward run `ps -aux | grep mongodb`. The goal here is to get all the parameters that mongodb is started with. Once you find them you can copy and paste it into your shell and add whatever arguments you need.

*Long Way:* 2 options: See if you can set it in `/etc/mongodb.conf` which theoretically has all the arguments there or see if there is an upstart configuration file in one of the defaults folders

Comment: Ah, I like the first one. Hadn't considered that. Thanks.